# A relation about dependence on a collection of random variables.

Tags: probability, relations, independence

Consider a collection $\mathcal R$ of random variables $X_\alpha$ on the same sample space.
Let $\sim$ be a relation on $\mathcal R$, defined by $X_\alpha\sim X_\beta$ if they are dependent.

What can we say about this relation?

More specifically, I might concentrate on the rolling dice (twice) example.
Being a discrete case, $X$ and $Y$ is independent if and only if 
$$P(X=x,Y=y)=P(X=x)P(Y=y)$$
for all $(x,y)\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}^2$.
Thus $\sim$ is fairly symmetric.

Let $X$ be the first number and $Y$ the second.
And let $Z=X+Y$.
Then $X\not\sim Y$, $X\sim Z$, and $Y\sim Z$, since, for example,
$$P(X=3,Z=5)=\frac1{36}\neq\frac16\times\frac4{36}=P(X=3)P(Z=5).$$
So $\sim$ is not transitive.

How about the reflectivity?
And is it meaningful to think of this kind of relation?

Comment: Every random variable $X$ is dependent on itself.

Comment: In your post, shouldn't $5/36$ be $4/36$?

Comment: As to whether the relation is meaningful, sure, it's a valid binary relation, but it's just the negation of the independence relation. However you shouldn't denote the relation by $\sim$ since that suggests an equivalence relation, and as you showed, it need not be.

Comment: @quasi Right it should be 4/36. Thanks

Comment: @quasi I see, so I might say that the relation is reflective. I chose 'dependence' since 'independence' is no better than 'dependence'. Independence relation is symmetric and transitive, but not reflective.... right?

Comment: The term is "reflexive", not "reflective".

Comment: What makes you think independence is transitive? For example if $X,Y$ are independent, then letting $Z=X$, we have $X$ is independent of $Y$, and $Y$ is independent of $Z$, but $X$ is not independent of $Z$.